# Php variable in script

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have this code:

```
<script>
newTextBoxDiv.after().html(<?php echo $do_shortcode('[dropdown]') ?>'<span class="wpcf7-form-         control-wrap text-73'+ counter + '"> '+ '<input type="text" name="text-73'+ counter + '" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false"></span>'+'pocet<br>');
newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#test");
</script>
```

After `.html(` I need get value from php. Could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Is there a problem with the code you have? What is it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate proper Javascript. You're not. What you're doing is the equivalent of:

```
... .html(some text from php'<span....);
          ^---no opening quote
                           ^---no closing quote
                            ^--- no + to concatenate
```

Never EVER directly echo text from PHP to Javascript. Always use json_encode():

```
... .html(<?php echo json_encode($do_shortcode('[dropdown'])) ?> + '<span ...
```

Of course, this assumes that whatever function that `$do_shortcode` is pointing at will return some plain text. Adjust as needed for whatever it DOES return.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure that your file is being evaluated as PHP - that is, its a .php file

2) Test to see if `echo "aaa"` works instead of `echo $do_shortcode` to see if PHP evaluation is working, but what isn't working is the "do short code" part. That will help you troubleshoot.

3) Use View Source to inspect the output.

Answer (score 0):

Pls dont do thinks link this. 
if you already have your data when you running the php scripte, why do you need javascript for rendering?

when you have to do it with javascript or you dont have your data at the point of rendering: use ajax.

Its simply confusing to render javascript with php that generates html.